# How to save a part/ few-lines of stdout_lines in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm currently registering a very big output say something like this

My current playbook is as follows

```
---
- name: Initialize Kubernetes Master.
  shell: "kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr={{ flannel_pod_cidr }} --service-cidr {{ service_cidr }}"
  register: master_initialization

- debug:
    msg: "{{ master_initialization.stdout_lines }}"
```

and the Output is as follows.

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.10.5", 
        "[init] Using Authorization modes: [Node RBAC]", 
        "[preflight] Running pre-flight checks.", 
        "[preflight] Starting the kubelet service", 
        "[certificates] Generated ca certificate and key.", 
        "[certificates] Generated apiserver certificate and key.", 
        "[certificates] apiserver serving cert is signed for DNS names [n0 kubernetes kubernetes.default kubernetes.default.svc kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local] and IPs [10.96.0.1 192.168.3.120]", 
        "[certificates] Generated apiserver-kubelet-client certificate and key.", 
        "[certificates] Generated sa key and public key.", 
        "[certificates] Generated front-proxy-ca certificate and key.", 
        "[certificates] Generated front-proxy-client certificate and key.", 
        "[certificates] Generated etcd/ca certificate and key.", 
        "[certificates] Generated etcd/server certificate and key.", 
        "[certificates] etcd/server serving cert is signed for DNS names [localhost] and IPs [127.0.0.1]", 
        "[certificates] Generated etcd/peer certificate and key.", 
        "[certificates] etcd/peer serving cert is signed for DNS names [n0] and IPs [192.168.3.120]", 
        "[certificates] Generated etcd/healthcheck-client certificate and key.", 
        "[certificates] Generated apiserver-etcd-client certificate and key.", 
        "[certificates] Valid certificates and keys now exist in \"/etc/kubernetes/pki\"", 
        "[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: \"/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf\"", 
        "[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: \"/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf\"", 
        "[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: \"/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf\"", 
        "[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: \"/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf\"", 
        "[controlplane] Wrote Static Pod manifest for component kube-apiserver to \"/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml\"", 
        "[controlplane] Wrote Static Pod manifest for component kube-controller-manager to \"/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml\"", 
        "[controlplane] Wrote Static Pod manifest for component kube-scheduler to \"/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml\"", 
        "[etcd] Wrote Static Pod manifest for a local etcd instance to \"/etc/kubernetes/manifests/etcd.yaml\"", 
        "[init] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as Static Pods from directory \"/etc/kubernetes/manifests\".", 
        "[init] This might take a minute or longer if the control plane images have to be pulled.", 
        "[apiclient] All control plane components are healthy after 24.502257 seconds", 
        "[uploadconfig] Storing the configuration used in ConfigMap \"kubeadm-config\" in the \"kube-system\" Namespace", 
        "[markmaster] Will mark node n0 as master by adding a label and a taint", 
        "[markmaster] Master n0 tainted and labelled with key/value: node-role.kubernetes.io/master=\"\"", 
        "[bootstraptoken] Using token: ggemtm.cybal0z01y1arkgi", 
        "[bootstraptoken] Configured RBAC rules to allow Node Bootstrap tokens to post CSRs in order for nodes to get long term certificate credentials", 
        "[bootstraptoken] Configured RBAC rules to allow the csrapprover controller automatically approve CSRs from a Node Bootstrap Token", 
        "[bootstraptoken] Configured RBAC rules to allow certificate rotation for all node client certificates in the cluster", 
        "[bootstraptoken] Creating the \"cluster-info\" ConfigMap in the \"kube-public\" namespace", 
        "[addons] Applied essential addon: kube-dns", 
        "[addons] Applied essential addon: kube-proxy", 
        "", 
        "Your Kubernetes master has initialized successfully!", 
        "", 
        "To start using your cluster, you need to run the following as a regular user:", 
        "", 
        "  mkdir -p $HOME/.kube", 
        "  sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config", 
        "  sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config", 
        "", 
        "You should now deploy a pod network to the cluster.", 
        "Run \"kubectl apply -f [podnetwork].yaml\" with one of the options listed at:", 
        "  https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/addons/", 
        "", 
        "You can now join any number of machines by running the following on each node", 
        "as root:", 
        "", 
        "  kubeadm join 192.168.3.120:6443 --token ggemtm.cybal0z01y1arkgi --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:36bf317da504025cfed2835d42f817ca83d056fedd12d9d6e1522d7d28a4bd65"
    ]
}
```

and I want to get the last lines i.e

```
"  kubeadm join 192.168.3.120:6443 --token ggemtm.cybal0z01y1arkgi --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:36bf317da504025cfed2835d42f817ca83d056fedd12d9d6e1522d7d28a4bd65"
```

How can I get only this line and store it a variable so that I can use it somewhere else??

any help would be of great use...

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the stdout into a log file by editing the `anisble.cfg` or set Environment variable `ANISBLE_LOG_PATH={PATH}` and then parse the file from python. Later on, you can set the variable in the `group_vars` and use it in ansible.
This all can be done on the runtime using python.

For further reading, you can check the ansible module `lineinfile` and `blockinfile`  ansible modules.